Pipenv install dependencies from pipfile.lock
I want to share an environment I've made with a colleague. I have both a Pipfile and a Pipfile.lock. I know the dependencies in Pipfile.lock work for our project, and I want to share these so they can work on the project without worrying about version issues.
I've looked through multiple questions, such as this one, this one and this one trying to find the command to do so. I've also looked at Pipenv's documentation, but I still do not see any clear mention of a command to install dependencies from the lock file.
The problem
As I understand it, pipenv install . installs dependencies from the Pipfile in the directory and updates the Pipenv.lock file accordingly.
What is the command to install the dependencies stored in Pipfile.lock?

Found the answer in this question. You just need to run pipenv sync.
